# How to write inductor ODE equation properly?

Tags: current, inductor, differential, kirchhoffs-laws, equation

I've drawn a following scheme, and now want to write [ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) system for describing inner processes, in order to explore it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhvTt9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I wrote the first part, and it is clear enough, as I have a leaky capacitor:

\$\frac{dV_m}{dt} = \frac{I_{in} - \frac{V_m}{R_m} - I_a*SW1}{C_m}\$

But second part is not clear at all, and is not working. I thought like it should work basically the same as capacitor:

\$\frac{dI_a}{dt} = \frac{V_m*SW1 - \frac{I_a}{R_a}}{L_a}\$

It kind of creates knee on current graph(when i close switch) - follow the red arrow on following screenshot:
[image]

Green knee is ok, its just due to `Iin` set to zero via heaviside function somewhere else in program, *sorry for it, just distracts*.

But for red I feel that desired behaviour should be like sinc stuff, so what was expected is like this, because it has some `L`:
[image]

So.. Could you correct me? Or, how to write correct formulas, describing processes in this circuit?

---

### PS

For the curious, its real-world warm-lamp doomsday device. It connects directly to the mains through series lamp, its very dangerous, so you should not do this at home: It has +310VDC on a thyristor radiator..

[image]

Comment: What does "ODE" stand for?

Comment: @Transistor [Ordinary differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation)

Comment: Thanks. By the way, when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks, I've used it. Felt like awesome button!

Comment: Look up the mathjax format and edit your post. Those equations will be a lot more legible when you do.

Comment: @Toor Done, I did requested edits. Thanks I know latex basics, but.. I thought that it is just supported on math.SE; and also, I am programmer, so first syntax is far-far more convenient for practical applications (copy-paste to/from code)

Comment: The impedance and ratios determine the ODE coefficients.  T=L/R , LC=1/ω²  .. .. danger high voltage ... (lol) http://tinyurl.com/y35d5uvq

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 ya that's my model of [giant squid propulsion neuron/axon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_giant_axon) (lol). It does not occillate, because thyrystor does not conducts backwards.. Now I need to write the simulator as in your link. It feels like I need two or three ODE's to write

Comment: There are only 2 switch states and different initial conditions.  I don't see the connection with the squid but the model may be more like a SMPS with zero valley current (ZVC) switching and peak voltage switching.  I can make this simulator oscillate with specs for voltage or current controlled switches.

Comment: WIthout no idea what your real parameters are, here is a relaxation oscillator like a Giant Squid axon  http://tinyurl.com/yyh2svke

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I want to write a simulation, more like in your links. So I need couple of equations for my schematics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93072/discussion-between-xakepp35-and-sunnyskyguy-ee75).

Comment: Your 2nd part shudbe  \$\frac{dI_a}{dt} = \frac{V_m*SW1-I_a \cdot R_a}{L_a}\$

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 wut. Since when could we use MathJax in the comments?

Comment: I dunno........

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get that up and running: http://jsfiddle.net/zo2xuhds/embedded/result/

Trick was in a wrong gate logic. A gate must:

- **transfer** power in one direction, from capacitor to inductor, but not vice versa (not sure if there are real-world analogs, maybe triac?..)
- **open** when a capacitor absolute voltage exceeds some threshold Vopen (no matter negative or positive),
- **close** when current will become less than holding current `Ihold` (again, no matter of its sign)

*@SunnyskyguyEE75* mentioned mistake in inductor ODE: Indeed, the `Ia⋅Ra` is correct term. I've messed resistances up with conductances, which are typically used in neuronal studies.

Certainly, what was noticed during my home-made research, is that:

- `Cm`(membrane capacitance) and `La`(axon inductance) are responsive for frequency ranges and may be chosen low and even fixed.
- timestep `dt(=1)` and cap leakage `Gm(=1/Rm)` are rarely useful and could almost be omitted from model.
- `Ra` and `Vopen` are capable of producing chaotic behaviours, and different kinds of tonic bursts: [image][image][image]

Such a simple thing is capable of creating non-linear pwm signals

Very pleased with it, I've finally done that, without [using exponentials](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Adaptive_exponential_integrate-and-fire_model), and [even squaring](https://www.izhikevich.org/publications/spikes.htm). Probably that puts some restrictions on the model's computational power, but I haven't figured out them yet.